# How to prevent the whole server getting locked during the ALTER of an unrelated table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, freeze

On a production server, I have two databases :

- **db**, which is where the common queries are performed
- **db_archive**, which contains old data purged from db

On db_archive, There is a table **x**, 1.3 Go size, InnoDB. That table has no foreign key (and no keys whatsoever). On db_archive, there is no query (or connection) other than the one I am performing :

`ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN z INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL AFTER y;`

I follow the progress of the reconstruction of `x` on the server, with `watch 'du -m \#* x.*'`. On the begining, everything goes well. Reconstruction progresses, and `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` is clean (< 30 opened connections).

At some point around 925 Mo (over 1342 Mo), the reconstruction freezes, and a `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` shows connections piling up on `db`.

This goes until the connection limit is reached (2000 connections), rendering the server unavailable. At that point, I have no choice but to kill the query, to avoid too much damage to production.

MySQL version is `5.2.12-MariaDB` on Debian `6.0.5`.

I know there are solutions to *avoid* this issue (eg. moving db_archive to another server), however, I just don't understand how the `db` database can be affected by an operation on another database without any relationship.

Comment: There is no reason why it should.  If the connections are piling up, the question is *why*?  What were all of those connections trying to do, as shown in the processlist?  Is it possible that you have a foreign key constraint that incorrectly references the table being altered?

Comment: I've removed all keys except the primary key from table x, as I said : no foreign keys

Answer (score 0):

Look more closely at the `PROCESSLIST`.  I expect you to find an archive process that is locking a table it is reading from in `db` while writing to `db_archive`.  The largest values in the `Time` column are likely to indicate the villain(s).

That `ALTER` may be involved, or it may be a red herring.

Here is a common pattern of unexpected locks:

1. A lengthy `SELECT` is reading table1.
2. Some write (`ALTER` qualifies) tries to get to table1, but it is in a transaction or otherwise touching table2.  The `SELECT` blocks the write to table1, so the write hangs.
3. Now even `SELECTs` on table1 and table2 may be blocked.